# AFNetworking return (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have built a code which gets data from a JSON file on the web.
I want to get the content of the JSON file and print it (via `NSLog`).

But, there is a problem. the program return `null`..
Here's what is says: `DataString: (null)`.
Why is that happening? I want the content of the JSON file..

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSString * requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager GET:requestURL parameters:nil

      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { //if success
          NSData * getData = operation.responseData;
          NSDictionary * jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(getData) options:kNilOptions error:nil];
          NSString * idFromJson = jsonResponse[@"id"];
          NSLog(@"DataString: %@", operation.responseString);
          //NSLog(@"Data: %@", getData);

          UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Loaded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
          [alert show];
      }

      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { // if failed
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

          UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error loading data. Please check your internet connection or try again later." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
          [alert show];

      }];

    [op start];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Added from a comment by the OP:
now, i get this: DataString:

```
<fffe7b00 20000d00 0a002200 69006400 22002000 3a002000 22003100 34003000 38003700 34003900 37003300 39003300 33003400 22002c00 0d000a00 22007400 69007400 6c006500 22002000 3a002000 2200e405 d905e705 d505d305 2000d405 e205d505 e805e305 2000d405 ea05e805 e205d405 2000d105 de05e805 d705d105 20002200 2c000d00 0a002200 64006100 74006100 22002000 3a002000 5b005d00 0d000a00 7d000d00 0a000d00 0a00>
```

---

My response code is 200 because I'm in Israel.
The problem is that I can't get the .json file content.

Comment: NSLog `operation.responseData`.

Comment: what is the contents of "responseObject" that the block gives you as a parameter ? [manager GET:requestURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)

Comment: NSLog(@"responseObject:%@",responseObject)

Comment: BTW, the `GET` method adds the request operation to the operation queue. Do not `start` it again.

Comment: the contents of "responseObject" is: responseObject:<fffe7b00 20000d00 0a002200 69006400 22002000 3a002000 22003100 34003000 38003800 31003300 31003900 34003100 30003100 22002c00 0d000a00 22007400 69007400 6c006500 22002000 3a002000 2200e405 d905e705 d505d305 2000d405 e205d505 e805e305 2000d405 ea05e805 e205d405 2000d105 de05e805 d705d105 20002200 2c000d00 0a002200 64006100 74006100 22002000 3a002000 5b005d00 0d000a00 7d000d00 0a000d00 0a00>

Comment: So, what is that converted to NSString?  Likely there's an error message, but I'm not going to spend 15 minutes with an ASCII table translating it.

Comment: @HotLicks See Zaph's answer. He shows you the UTF16 representation: `{ 
"id" : "1408749739334",
"title" : "פיקוד העורף התרעה במרחב ",
"data" : []
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the data by @Itay Pincas as a comment to @Dima Goltsman

The data is in UTF-16 with BOM format, This is rather unusual as UTF-8 is the general response format. The key is the first two bytes: `fffe`.

```
// Create the data from the question:  
uint16_t utf16Bytes[] = {0xfffe, 0x7b00, 0x2000, 0x0d00, 0x0a00, 0x2200, 0x6900, 0x6400, 0x2200, 0x2000, 0x3a00, 0x2000, 0x2200, 0x3100, 0x3400, 0x3000, 0x3800, 0x3700, 0x3400, 0x3900, 0x3700, 0x3300, 0x3900, 0x3300, 0x3300, 0x3400, 0x2200, 0x2c00, 0x0d00, 0x0a00, 0x2200, 0x7400, 0x6900, 0x7400, 0x6c00, 0x6500, 0x2200, 0x2000, 0x3a00, 0x2000, 0x2200, 0xe405, 0xd905, 0xe705, 0xd505, 0xd305, 0x2000, 0xd405, 0xe205, 0xd505, 0xe805, 0xe305, 0x2000, 0xd405, 0xea05, 0xe805, 0xe205, 0xd405, 0x2000, 0xd105, 0xde05, 0xe805, 0xd705, 0xd105, 0x2000, 0x2200, 0x2c00, 0x0d00, 0x0a00, 0x2200, 0x6400, 0x6100, 0x7400, 0x6100, 0x2200, 0x2000, 0x3a00, 0x2000, 0x5b00, 0x5d00, 0x0d00, 0x0a00, 0x7d00, 0x0d00, 0x0a00, 0x0d00,  0x0a00};
```

Decode with `encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding`:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:utf16Bytes length:sizeof(utf16Bytes)];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str: '%@'", str);
```

Output:

```
str: '{
    "id" : "1408749739334",
    "title" : "פיקוד העורף התרעה במרחב ",
    "data" : []
}
```

For a dictionary object:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

NSLog(@"id:    %@", dict[@"id"]);
NSLog(@"title: %@", dict[@"title"]);
NSLog(@"data:  %@", dict[@"data"]);
```

Output:

```
title: פיקוד העורף התרעה במרחב
id:    1408749739334
data:  ()
```

From the `JSONObjectWithData` docs:

> The data in the stream must be in one of the 5 supported encodings
>   listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE,
>   UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient
>   encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in
>   encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

Comment: i did it..it says "use of undeclared identifier 'uf16Bytes"

Comment: Use the code following: "For a dictionary object" and use `getData` from your code. That is use the same data that you dumped for the comment you made to @Dima Goltsman.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL has access rights only in israel. if your server is located in another place, or if you sent too many requests to this URL, you will get `Access Denied` response.

your response code is probably 403, you can get it with

`NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;`

Comment: now, i get this:
DataString: <fffe7b00 20000d00 0a002200 69006400 22002000 3a002000 22003100 34003000 38003700 34003900 37003300 39003300 33003400 22002c00 0d000a00 22007400 69007400 6c006500 22002000 3a002000 2200e405 d905e705 d505d305 2000d405 e205d505 e805e305 2000d405 ea05e805 e205d405 2000d105 de05e805 d705d105 20002200 2c000d00 0a002200 64006100 74006100 22002000 3a002000 5b005d00 0d000a00 7d000d00 0a000d00 0a00>

Comment: please check what is the response code of your request, probably its not 200

Comment: I wrote the the result i get, you told me it looks like bytes

Comment: this is how you get response code:
 `NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;`

Comment: no you didnt. you only getting the response String, not the response status code which is `NSInteger`

Comment: and what was the string?

Comment: i dont understand..
thats the code:
NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)statusCode);

Comment: That's the code i've inserted:
NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)statusCode);

i dont understand what do you mean by "the string"

Comment: It is interesting that the received data is UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

The URL demands access rights. You did not include those in your request.

Comment: So how can i include those in my request?

Comment: I don't use AFNetworking because it produces too much code and does not add value. The normal Objective-C API for this is the NSURLConnection delegate's `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`. Check the AFNetworking docs.